# Changing div opacity one by one to make animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to create a animation with the help of four boxes, each of the square should change opacity one by one to make a loading type animation, I tried with CSS, but not able to achieve, can anyone help with this `CSS` animation?

Here is the working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/60jnk66d/1/)

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -22.5px;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
ul li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  
  /*animation: dance 888ms infinite alternate;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.block-1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:#0076aa;
}
.block-2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:#98bd81; 
}
.block-3 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:#98bd81;
}
.block-4 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:#0076aa;
}
li.block-1 {
  animation-delay: 222ms;
}
li.block-2 {
  animation-delay: 444ms;
}
li.block-3 {
  animation-delay: 666ms;
}
li.block-4 {
  animation-delay: 888ms;
}
@keyframes dance {
  to {
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <ul class='blocks'>
    <li class='block-1'></li>
    <li class='block-2'></li>
    <li class='block-3'></li>
    <li class='block-4'></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is after fixing your code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes dance {
      from {
        opacity: 1
      }
      to {
        opacity: 0.1
      }
}

li.block-1 {
      animation: dance 1s infinite;
      animation-delay: 222ms;
      animation-direction: alternate;
    }
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xvfonn3f/)

You can fine tune the value to your preference :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the animation call to your `li` elements otherwise it wont run.

Using the `animation` shorthand property you can achieve this.

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -22.5px;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
ul li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  
  /*animation: dance 888ms infinite alternate;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);*/
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation: dance 888ms infinite alternate;
}

.block-1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:#0076aa;
  
}

.block-2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:#98bd81;
  
  
}

.block-3 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:#98bd81;
  
  
}

.block-4 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:#0076aa;
}

li.block-1 {
  animation-delay: 222ms;
}

li.block-2 {
  animation-delay: 444ms;
}

li.block-3 {
  animation-delay: 666ms;
}

li.block-4 {
  animation-delay: 888ms;
}

@keyframes dance {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <ul class='blocks'>
    <li class='block-1'></li>
    <li class='block-2'></li>
    <li class='block-3'></li>
    <li class='block-4'></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me..

```
    body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -22.5px;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
ul li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;

  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.block-1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:#0076aa;


}

.block-2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:#98bd81;


}

.block-3 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background:#98bd81;


}

.block-4 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:#0076aa;

}

li.block-1 {
  animation: dance 1.5s ease-out infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.91s;


}

li.block-2 {
animation: dance 1.5s ease-out infinite;
animation-delay: 1.54s;

}

li.block-3 {
animation: dance 1.5s ease-out infinite;
animation-delay: 1.77s;

}

li.block-4 {
 animation: dance 1.5s ease-out infinite; 
 animation-delay: 1.99s;

}

@keyframes dance {
    50%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `opacity: 0` property in your animation like so: 
https://jsfiddle.net/60jnk66d/6/

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,
 html {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 
 body {
   background-color: #efefef;
 }
 
 .wrapper {
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -22.5px;
   margin-left: -22.5px;
 }
 
 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   position: relative;
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 
 ul li {
   width: 2em;
   height: 2em;
   position: absolute;
   /*animation: dance 888ms infinite alternate;
   animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);*/
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
      border-radius:50%;
 }
 
 .block-1 {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #0076aa;
 }
 
 .block-2 {
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   background: #98bd81;
 }
 
 .block-3 {
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   background: #98bd81;
 }
 
 .block-4 {
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #0076aa;
 }
 
 li.block-1 {
   animation: dance 1s infinite;
   animation-delay: 222ms;
   animation-direction: alternate;
 }
 
 li.block-2 {
   animation: dance 1s infinite;
   animation-delay: 444ms;
   animation-direction: alternate;
 }
 
 li.block-3 {
   animation: dance 1s infinite;
   animation-delay: 666ms;
   animation-direction: alternate;
 }
 
 li.block-4 {
   animation: dance 1s infinite;
   animation-delay: 888ms;
   animation-direction: alternate;
 }
 
 @keyframes dance {
   from {
     opacity: 1
   }
   to {
     opacity: 0.1
   }
 }
 
 @-webkit-keyframes dance {
   from {
     opacity: 1
   }
   to {
     opacity: 0.1
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <ul class='blocks'>
    <li class='block-1'></li>
    <li class='block-2'></li>
    <li class='block-3'></li>
    <li class='block-4'></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Try It